# How to remove ambiguity from this piece of Delphi grammar

Tags: rascal

I'm working on a Delphi Grammar in Rascal and I'm having some problems parsing its “record” type. The relevant section of Delphi code can look as follows:

```
record

private 
a,b,c : Integer;
x : Cardinal;

end
```

Where the "private" can be optional, and the variable declaration lines can also be optional.

I tried to interpret this section using the rules below:

```
syntax FieldDecl    = IdentList ":" Type 
        | IdentList ":" Type ";"
        ;

syntax FieldSection = FieldDecl
        | "var" FieldDecl
        | "class" "var" FieldDecl
        ;

syntax Visibility = "private" | "protected" | "public"| "published" ; 

syntax VisibilitySectionContent = FieldSection
            | MethodOrProperty
            | ConstSection
            | TypeSection
            ;

syntax VisibilitySection = Visibility? VisibilitySectionContent+    
         ;

syntax RecordType   = "record" "end"
        | "record" VisibilitySection+  "end"
        ;
```

Problem is ambiguity. The entire text between “record” and “end” can be parsed in a single VisibilitySection, but every line on its own can also be a seperate VisibilitySection.

I can change the rule VisibilitySection to

```
syntax VisibilitySection = Visibility 
         | VisibilitySectionContent
         ;
```

Then the grammar is no longer ambiguous, but the VisibilitySection becomes, flat, there is no nesting anymore of the variable lines under an optional 'private' node, which I would prefer.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? What I would like to do is demand a longest /greedy match on the VisibilitySectionContent+ symbol of VisibilitySection.

But changing

```
syntax VisibilitySection = Visibility? VisibilitySectionContent+
```

to

```
syntax VisibilitySection = Visibility? VisibilitySectionContent+ !>> VisibilitySectionContent
```

does not seem to work for this.

I also ran the Ambiguity report tool on Rascal, but it does not provide me any insights.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: hi. I can't reproduce the ambiguity because the grammar is incomplete. do you have a reference to the full definition?

Comment: the `!>>` notation only works with terminals on the right-hand side, like `!>> "private"`

Comment: The grammar so far is at: http://www.ilsmoija.nl/download/DelphiGrammar.rsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't check since you did not provide the full grammar, but I believe this should work to get your "longest match" behavior:

```
syntax VisibilitySection 
  = Visibility? VisibilitySectionContent+ () 
  >> "public" 
  >> "private" 
  >> "published"
  >> "protected"
  >> "end"
  ;
```

In my mind this should remove the interpretation where your nested VisibilitySections are cut short. Now we only accept such sections if they are immediately followed by either the end of the record, or the next section. I'm curious to find out if it really works because it is always hard to predict the behavior of a grammar :-)

The `()` at the end of the rule (empty non-terminal) makes sure we can skip to the start of the next part before applying the restriction. This only works if you have a longest match rule on layout already somewhere in the grammar.

Comment: This works almost perfectly, although every 'follows' operator seems to need to be in its own production rule. Problem is that layout does not seem to be considered between the VisibilitySectionContent section and the "private" part? When not having any layout parts in between, it parses perfectly, but when layout is added, it generates an parse error. When layout parts to be expected are explicitly added to the rule, it is ambiguous on the double whitespace part.

Comment: ah yes, indeed. I will change the solution with another workaround for this. If it then works, please accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `VisibilitySectionContent+` in `VisibilitySection` should be `VisibilitySectionContent` (without the Kleene plus).

I’m guessing here, but your intention is probably to allow a number of sections/declarations within the record type, and any of those may or may not have a `Visibility` modifier. To avoid putting this optional `Visibility` in every section, you have created a `VisibilitySectionContent` nonterminal which basically models “things that can happen within the record type definition”, one thing per nonterminal, without worrying about visibility modifiers. In this case, you’re fine with one `VisibilitySectionContent` per `VisibilitySection` since there is explicit repetition when you refer to the `VisibilitySection` from the `RecordType` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but when I use this method, the inner structure of the record becomes 'flat', and I like to preserve the nesting of the variables under the "private" and "public" tags.